# F# WPF Esri Developer License

Tags: wpf, xaml, f#, esri

I have gone to [License your app](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/license-your-app.htm) and  there is only code for C#. I am wondering where to place the license information in my F# WPF application. 
Does it go in the app.fs file or a different one.

Thanks

Comment: you could frame it though in a more general way, like how would you write this C# code in F#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this SDK but it should go into the assembly (so exe or dll) file that uses it. It would've been helpful to show the C# code, and not just the link:

```
Esri.ArcGISRuntime.ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.ClientId = "mYcLieNTid";

try
{
    Esri.ArcGISRuntime.ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.Initialize();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to initialize the ArcGIS Runtime with the client ID provided: " + ex.Message);
```

}

From the recently much improved F# docs [Try/With](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/exceptions-the-try...with-expression-%5Bfsharp%5D/) is the equivalent exception handling mechanism in F#:

```
Esri.ArcGISRuntime.ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.ClientId <- "mYcLieNTid";

try
    Esri.ArcGISRuntime.ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.Initialize()
with
    | ex -> printfn "Unable to initialize the ArcGIS Runtime with the client ID provided: %A" ex.Message
```

**Additional Info:** If you have time please take a look at [F# for fun](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/organizing-functions/) and also [Modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/modules-%5Bfsharp%5D/) and [Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/namespaces-%5Bfsharp%5D/), you can also search these topics on SO. Here are some comments:

1. F# is sensitive to the file order in the project, please make sure that you put  your module above the file that is `open`-ing it
2. you generally `#load *.fsx` scripts, you can but you don't need to do this for `*.fs` files, as those assumed to be built into an assembly. You can just say `open File1` assuming you have a File1.fs and inside it a `module File1`, then if inside the File1 module you have let `let x = 5`, you can  say `File1.x` to access it
3. You don't need to put a module into a separate file. You can just place it ino the namespace you have your SDK in (maybe `App.fs`).
4. Easiest would be to actually put this code inside your `main` function, in the `[<EntryPoint>]`

Comment: thanks for your input on showing the C# code as a baseline example. I will be working on this issue this weekend and will reply back to see how the F# code works.

Comment: I copied the code directly in both the MainWindow and App files and got this Error: Namespaces cannot contain values. Consider using a module to hold your value declarations. So I created the module ApKey.fs and add  open ApKey to either MainWindow or App files and now getting this  Error The namespace or module 'Apkey' is not defined. I referenced #load "ApKey.fs" and still getting the error.

Comment: Well, that's really another question. Please see the *Additional Info* in my answer above.

Comment: Added the code above the [<STAThread>]
[<EntryPoint>] and now the Developer Use tag is remove. Thanks alot